# setInterval, recursion, timer Id

Tags: javascript, timing

I've this animation example from a tutorial that I'm watching:

```
(function() {

 var speed = 10,
 moveBox = function(moveBy) {
    var el = document.getElementById("box"),
        left = el.offsetLeft;


    if ((moveBy > 0 && left > 399) || (moveBy < 0 && left < 51)) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            moveBox(moveBy * -1);
        }, speed);
    }

    el.style.left = left + moveBy + "px";

};

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    moveBox(3);
}, speed);
}());
```

I'm just curious how the clearTimeout (timer) does not that throw error as timer is being defined after the clearTimeout function..

Comment: Because of hoisting. `clearTimeout(undefined)` is fine, shouldn't throw error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript variables are hoisted to the top of the enclosing scope so your code is, more or less, equivalent to this:

```
(function() {
    var speed = undefined;
    var moveBox = undefined;
    var timer = undefined;

    speed = 10;
    moveBox = function(moveBy) { /* Stuff that uses timer ... */ };

    timer = setInterval(function () { ... }, speed);
}());
```

It doesn't matter where the `var timer` is as it gets hoisted to the top and `timer` is declared for the whole function.

The [MDN docs on `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) have some information on hoisting.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript looks at all the code before any execution begins.

JS first creates an executionContext.

Then JS records a reference to all functions and variables and they are are stored in the variableObject of the executionContext.

This means before javascript starts executing code, it "knows" about all functions and all variables before it even begins parsing the execution order.

See this link for more info which explains how JS creates closures, but also explains in general how JS compiles code:  http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/